# How to remove merge commits while keeping merged changes?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have our commit log from my repo. You can see the "Merge branch...into..." commits. After these commits, the branch was merged.

I need to delete the merge commits, but not discard the changes.
Default rebasing doesn't show merge commits.

[image: screenshot of the repo history]

Comment: So you want to do a soft reset?

Comment: No, i dont want to reset any changes. I want to only "hide" that merge branch commits. Cause they are there double. One as merge and one as commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git remove merge commit from history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577409/git-remove-merge-commit-from-history)

Comment: What do you mean by "hiding commits"? You made it sound like you want to undo the commits, but keep the changes (which is soft resetting)

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what information a merge commit represents.  It's a marker that indicates where two branches became one in history, which is useful if you ever need to revert a particular merge (it gets complicated if you have to revert a fast-forward merge).

Comment: If you want to keep the information, then you can’t remove those commits.

Comment: It is considered [good practice](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to keep merge commits on feature branches.

Comment: What do you mean by "they are there double"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to apply the changes of the commits without including the merge commit (which as Roland Smith pointed out is generally considered bad practice) you can use `git rebase` with the following workflow:

1. Checkout the branch you want the changes to be on (let's say master): `git checkout master`
2. Reset master to the commit before the merge you want to undo: `git reset --hard <hash of prior commit>`. Make sure there are no uncommitted changes on the branch you were working on or this command will wipe them out.
3. Checkout the branch containing the updates you want to "merge" to master without actually merging it (let's call it `dev`): `git checkout dev`.
4. Rebase `dev` onto master. This will put the `HEAD` commit of dev to be upstream to the most recent commit that master points to: `git rebase master` (see [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more information).
5. Fix any merge conflicts that result during the rebase (they would have happened in a normal merge too).
6. The rebased branch should now have all of its commits following the latest commit on master. To port this over to master, check out master (`git checkout master`) and merge the new branch `git merge dev`. This will pull the changes onto master without adding a merge commit.
7. Once you're sure the updated `master` branch looks okay, you'll have to update the branch on any remote repositories too. Because you're undoing prior history, when you push the branch you'll have to use the `--force` (or `-f`) flag for the remote repo to accept the changes i.e.: `git push origin master --force`.

That's all there is to it. After you do this, the commits on `dev` that were branched off of master should now be upstream to the pre-merge commit above.

NOTE: Running rebase will permanently update the commit history for the changed branches. For safety, I recommend taking 1 of 2 methods:

1. Per @Dacav's suggestion, keep track of the commit hashes for each branch before you update anything. If things go pear shaped, then just run `git reset --hard <original_commit_hash>` to put the branch back on the original commit.
2. Make backup copies of both branches before you rebase that are pointing at the original commit:

   git checkout -b master_bk
   git checkout -b dev_bk

Comment: Actually you don't need backup copies. Rebase will update the commit history, but the old branches will remain in history. You just need to write down the SHA identifiers of the original branches, and if problems arise you can simply reset the branches to their original places with `git reset --hard`

Comment: Good point! I'll update the answer to reflect this option as well

Comment: @Dacav Assuming they don't get garbage-collected already. Typically not a problem, but worth taking precautions against.

Comment: Yeah. Of course if you put a `git gc` in between you are going to remove them. It is possible also to run the `git gc` when you are sure your rebase succeded or after you rolled it back by resetting the involved branches. But I guess on average it's not worthy: the amount of space used is probably going to be negligible, unless the rebase is so dramatic...

Comment: @Dacav I mentioned it because `git gc --auto` is run automatically after many operations, including pretty much every commit. It typically sees there's no need for garbage collection yet, but you could be unlucky.

Comment: @hvd, I knew it runs periodically, I didn't think "periodically" means so often. Up to now I was clearly lucky then. Although it's also true I don't mess often with history that badly. Besides, since I'm quite bad at recording hash values, I usually put a tag in those cases, and this kills the problem in the crib.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. Some notes if you want to make the answer more clear. 1.  This assumes that the feature branch already exists which is not always true. For example the gitlab merge could be done with the "delete branch" enabled. 2. The step 3 needs to be a bit more explanatory as it is not clear if you need to checkout the commit with the feature changes or the one that was already on the master. If you continue reading it is easy to assume what you need to do, but it could better if it is written explicitly.