# Removing branch merged in history?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

How could I remove a branch I had merged into master in the past ?

From something like :

```
master
... a---> b ---> c ---------> d -----> e ---> f ---> g ---> h
                  \                   /
                    x ---> y ------> z
                     branch1
```

to :

```
... a---> b ---> c ---------> d -----> f ---> g ---> h
                  \                
                    x ---> y ---> z
                     branch1
```

I want to undo/remove merging of a branch into master I had done sometime earlier.

---

I have tried out something like but am getting conflicts. Is it possible ?

```
# currently we are in <h> commit in master branch
git checkout master   

# new temporary branch
git branch tmp_master 

git checkout tmp_master

# reseting temp. branch to reqd. commit
git reset <d> --hard  

# cherry-picking subsequent commits
git cherry-pick <f>..<h>
```

After it was done --as I had expected to do :

```
# change temp. branch to master branch
git branch -D master

git branch -m master
```

Comment: Look into [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: Seconded. Do an interactive rebase of master and delete commit `e`. Ditto with `branch1`.

Comment: Check out this question for a similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577409/git-remove-merge-commit-from-history

Comment: Although if branch 1 hasn't moved after the commit, you can just reset it back one.

Comment: You're getting *errors* or *conflicts*? If actual errors, then please share those, otherwise your approach is sound and likely what I would do.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII conflicts. As there number of commits, as I go resolving a conflict & `rebase --continue`, conflict for the next commit appears. Do I need to handle the same conflict in each step ?

Comment: Use [rerere](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) so you don't have to keep resolving the same conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase --onto d e` will remove `e` from the branch history of `h`. See [here](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/git-rebase-onto) for more information.

Comment: As there number of commits, as I go resolving a conflict & `rebase --continue`, conflict for the next commit appears. Do I need to handle the same conflict in each step ?

Comment: If subsequent commits depend upon something that was removed in `e`, then you will have to fix them up individually as far as I'm aware. However, someone else may know of a faster way (that I would definitely be interested in myself!).

Answer (score 1):

You either need to:

- `rebase --interactive` (which would allow you to drop "`e`", the merge commit),
- or `git revert -m 1 e` (see "[Undoing Merges](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) "), which creates a new commit cancelling the changes introduced by the merge.

The second solution allows for a simple push (you are pushing new commits), while the first solution would require a `push --force` (problematic in case of multiple user collaborating on the same remote repo)