# Revert merge without cancel commits done after

Tags: git, git-revert

I've a little problem. I need to cancel a merge on my remote repository without cancel commits done after. See below my model and my expectation.

*Currently, I've this model:*

[image]

*I would like this :*

[image]

I've check the docs and search on the web but I didn't find any smart solution. Do you have an idea for me ? I would take care about my merge on the future !

Thanks you very much !

Comment: Are you happy to do a force push, which will require getting anyone else with local copies of that branch to update their local copies before they can push?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git remove merge commit from history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577409/git-remove-merge-commit-from-history)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+merge+commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either rewrite branch history, or revert the merge.  Each has pros and cons.

First let's start with a slightly modified copy of you current-state diagram, that reflects a bit more of what's going on.

```
A -- B -- C <--(branch>
           \
  M -- N -- O -- P -- Q <--(master)
```

You didn't show any refs, so I'm assuming `master` is pointed at `Q`.  If you don't have a branch at `branch`, you should probably create one (unless you're permanently discarding the changes from `A`, `B`, and `C`).  Also, a minor point of notation, but I've switched all commits to letters (as this can sometimes be clearer).

---

*History Rewrite*

All of the usual warnings about history rewrites apply to this approach.  Mostly that means, if `master` has been pushed such that anyone else has already "seen" commit `O` as a part of `master`s history, then you will have to coordinate with them to successfully do a history rewrite.  The rewrite will put their copy of `master` in a bad state from which they'll have to recover, and if they do this the wrong way - as they might if you haven't communicated what's happening - then your work could be undone.  See "Recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` docs for more information, as that is the applicable condition whether or not you actually use the `rebase` command to perform the rewrite.

If you do want to do a rewrite, rebase is the simplest way.  You'll need either the IDs of commits `N` and `O`, or expressions that resolve to commits `N` and `O`.  In this example we can use `master~3` for `N` and `master~2` for `O`.

```
git rebase --onto master~3 master~2 master
```

This will take the changes reachable from `master`, but not reachable from `O`, and replay them over `N`; and then move `master` to the rewritten commits.

```
A -- B -- C <--(branch>
           \
  M -- N -- O -- P -- Q <--(master@{1})
        \
         P' -- Q` <--(master)
```

The old commits still exist (and, as I've shown here, the reflog could still reach them - locally for the time being).  Because most tools don't follow the reflog, you'll likely see something more like

```
A -- B -- C <--(branch>

M -- N -- P' -- Q` <--(master)
```

And in fact, after the reflog expires that's exactly what will remain (if you don't do something to preserve the old commits in the meantime).  At this point, to push `master` you would have to do a force push.  The safest way to do that is

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

It is common for people to recommend simply the `-f` option, but this is less safe as it could clobber commits you don't know about on the remote `master`.  In any event, after a force-push is the point where anyone else with copies of `master` will have to recover from the "upstream rebase" condition.

Other ways of doing the rewrite (such as by resetting and then cherry-picking) are functionally equivalent (barring a few weird edge cases), but they are more manual and therefore more error-prone.  Worth reiterating, even though such alternatives might not use the `rebase` command, the "upstream rebase" situation would still apply in exactly the same way.

---

*Without a Rewrite*

If a history rewrite is not feasible - as is often the case in widely-shared repos - the alternative is to revert the merge commit.  This creates a new commit that "undoes" the changes introduced by the merge.  To use `revert` on a merge commit, you have to give the `-m` option (which tells `revert` which parent to revert *to*; if you're trying to undo the effect of a merge this is usually `-m 1`).

Again you need the ID of, or an expression that resolves to, `O`; we'll use `master~2` in the example.

```
git checkout master
git revert -m 1 master~2
```

Now you have

```
A -- B -- C <--(branch>
           \
  M -- N -- O -- P -- Q -- !O <--(master)
```

where `!O` reverses the changes that `O` applied to `N`.

As noted elsewhere, git sees `branch` as "already accounted for" - it doesn't track that `!O`s changes were intended as a revert/rollback of `O` or anything like that.  So if you later want to say `git merge branch`, it will skip over commits `A`, `B`, and `C`.

One way to fix that is with `rebase -f`.  For example, after the revert you could say

```
git rebase -f master~3 branch
```

and all commits reachable from `branch`, but not reachable from `master` prior to the merge at `O`, would be rewritten.  Of course, this is a rewrite of `branch`.  Since you might've been using the `revert` approach to avoid rewriting `master`, you might also not want to rewrite `branch`.  (If you do rewrite `branch`, and if `branch` is shared with other repos, then you'd have to `push --force-with-lease` and other users would have to recover from an upstream rebase.)

Another option, at the point where you want to merge `branch` back into `master`, is to "revert the revert".  Let's suppose some time has passed since you reverted the merge, and you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E <--(branch>
           \
  M -- N -- O -- P -- Q -- !O -- R -- S <--(master)
```

Now to merge `branch` to `master` you could say

```
git checkout master
git revert master~2
git merge branch
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your excellent answer, I've learned a lot ! I've used the `git revert` solution :)

Comment: A question about the revert snippets: Initially, `master~2` was reverted using `git revert -m 1 master~2` (1st revert). But to revert that revert (2nd revert), we should again refer to the same commit `master~2`, running `git revert master~2`? shouldn't we refer to the 1st revert commit in some way, e.g. running `get revert master~3`, assuming `master~3` is the 1st revert?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to reset hard on the last commit before `O` which doesn't belong to the branch `5 - 6 - 7` i.e. `N` in this case.  Then cherry pick all the required commits i.e. `P` & `Q`. Example below:

```
git reset --hard N         #This resets the branch to N & removes all commits of merged branch `5 - 6 - 7`
git cherry-pick P          #Manually add the 2 commits you want back.
git cherry-pick Q
```

---

Another way is to revert the merge commit with the following command:

```
git revert -m 1 O .     #this is alphabet O - merge commit id. Not Numeric zero.
```

This will add a new commit on top of `Q` - Let's name it as `O'`, where

- `O'` is the reverse commit of `O`

**caveat:** If you try to do some changes in the `5 - 6 - 7` branch in future and merge it again - it won't merge commits `5`, `6`, `7` because those commit ids are already in this branch & there also exists a reverse commit of these commits on top of them.

This means you won't be ever able to merge commits `5`, `6`, `7`.

Though there are mechanisms by which you can change the commit ids by doing either a rebase or making a trivial change just for the sake of changing the ids, that would incur a merge conflict on identical changes. Personally, I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: The concerns about reverting the merge are vastly overstated, and this concerns about rewriting (possibly published) history are entirely ignored.  Someone's personal preferences are showing through.

Comment: I might have missed writing about histry rewrite but which part of the answer overstates anything and doesn't talk about facts?

Comment: "mechanisms by which you can change the commit ids ... would incur a merge conflict".  Not generally true.

Comment: I think the possibility of occurring is more than not occurring. If the changes are same in 2 commits but diff IDs, why do you think there wouldn't be any conflicts if you merge one on top of another?

Comment: You may think the possibility of occurring is more than not occurring, but you're mistaken.  The reasoning behind how such a merge works is complex enough that I'm not going to try to spell it out in a comment, but (1) search on the topic, and you'll find questions and answers that do spell it out, or (2) try it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PankajSinghal ! I didn't know the `git cherry-pick`. I've used the `git revert` solution :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mention anything about the branches you currently have, I suggest you start by creating some branches (`b7` and `bkp`) on the existing commits to keep them visible after the change:

```
        +----- b7
        v
5 - 6 - 7       +-------- bkp
        |       v
M - N - O - P - Q
                ^
                +-------- bQ
```

Since you probably have a branch that points to `Q` you can use it instead of `bQ` in the commands below.

Then [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) the commits `P` and `Q` on top of commit `N` to get the structure you desire.

The commands are:

```
# Preparations
# Create the branch `b7` to keep the commit `7` reachable after the change
git branch b7 7
# Create the branch `bkp` for backup (the commit `Q` will be discarded)
git branch bkp Q

# The operation
# Checkout `bQ` to start the change
git checkout bQ
# Move the `P` and `Q` commits on top of `N`
# Change "2" and "3" in the command below with the actual number of commits
# 2 == two commits: P and Q, 3 == 2 + 1
# Or you can use commit hashes (git rebase --onto N O)
git rebase --onto HEAD~3 HEAD~2
```

Now the repository looks like this:

```
        +----- b7
        v
5 - 6 - 7       +-------- bkp
        |       v
M - N - O - P - Q
    |
    P'- Q'
        ^
        +-------- bQ
```

The old `O`, `P` and `Q` commits are still there and they are still reachable as long as the branch `bkp` or any other branches that point to `Q` still exists. If you are happy with the change you can remove `bkp` and any other branches that point to Q you have.

The command is:

```
git branch -D bkp
```

You probably don't want to remove `b7` unless you already have another branch that points to commit `7` already. In this case you do not even need to create `b7`.

After this operation, the repo looks like this:

```
        +----- b7
        v
5 - 6 - 7

M - N - P'- Q'
            ^
            +-------- bQ
```

Please note that the commits `P'` and `Q'` are different than the original commits `P` and `Q`.

#### Warning

If the commits `O`, `P` and `Q` were already pushed to a remote repository (through the `bQ` branch), pushing `bQ` again will fail. The pushing can be forced ([`git push --force origin bQ`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--f)) but this action will confuse your coworkers that already fetched the current position of the `bQ` branch (it contains the `O`, `P` and `Q` commits).

If you really need to perform this stunt, make sure you inform everybody about this change.

A better approach in this situation is to [`git revert -m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert--mparent-number) the commit `O`. This creates a new commit on top of `Q` that introduces changes that cancel the changes introduced by commit `O`. It is ugly but it is the safest solution.

Comment: Since `O` is a merge commit, plain `git revert O` won't work. Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7099833/820410

Comment: Thank you for your answer !