# Remove multi merge feature branch in git history

Tags: git, merge, rebase, squash

I am currently converting a SVN repository to Git and during this process I want to make the history as linear as possible. The problem is that I have some feature branches in SVN which merges from the master branch during the process. This merging pattern makes rebaseing a pain and I cannot figure out how to do it properly.

My goal is to replace the merge of the feature branch with a squash commits:
[image]

I have studied the answer to this question but none of the suggested answers seems to work for my case:
[git remove merge commit from history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577409/git-remove-merge-commit-from-history)

How should I go about squashing my feature branch so that I can rebase it on master at the correct point in time?

Comment: Why is this so desired?

Comment: I would say that the desire to do this is uncommon. In this case I was importing an old SVN repo and wanted to clean up the repo a bit before starting using it as a Git repo. This cleanup entailed squashing together related commits, fixing commit messages. To be able to do squashing with interactive rebase I needed to get rid of these merge commits. Please note that this Git repo was not active yet, so I was fine with re-writing history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that `M` is the topmost merge commit (the one between `G` and `H`):

```
git checkout -b cleaned-branch M
git reset --soft G
git commit -m "Get rid of merge"
git rebase M `git rev-parse master` --onto cleaned-branch
git checkout -B cleaned-branch
```

`git reset --soft G` will make git think that `G` is your current base commit, but it does that without touching your files (unlike `checkout`), so you'll be left with all the changes from the merge in the form of outstanding changes, and the subsequent commit will just have `G` as its parent. Then, we rebase the remaining commits and move `cleaned-branch` up to the resulting tip commit.

Comment: I have tried this proposed solution and there are two problems:

1. The commit will have todays time/date instead of the time/date from the history of merge M.

2. When I am done I have a new branch 'cleaned-branch' which is parallel to the master branch. I want to only have the master branch.

Comment: Ok.. I have figured out how to change the date/time of the new commit to match the old date/time. i.e. by using the flag --date='2014-05-05T10:08:00' in the commit command.

Comment: Just finish of with `git checkout -B master` on the last line instead, which will move `master` to the rebased tip commit. Note that the resulting `master` commit will have a different hash than the original one, but that's inherent in git and impossible to avoid: _any_ manipulation of old commits will change the hash of the modified commits and _all_ their descendant commits.

Comment: Ok.. I solved it by doing:
`git checkout master` and then 
`git rebase --onto 'git rev-parse cleaned-branch' M 'git rev-parse master'`