# git rebasing a branch against later master

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Initially, I branched from master (A) and made a commit (B) on my feature branch...then merged in changes from master (C as D) and made another commit (E) *using* the changes from that merge:

```
-A--C
 \  \
  B--D--E
```

Now, I'd like to eliminate the merge commit itself (D) and clean up my branch's history by rebasing **my entire branch** against a *later* master (C):

```
-A--C
    \
    B--E
```

However, I am sufficiently confused about how to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you try `git rebase C E`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have, but it leaves me in a `HEAD detached` state

Comment: For `E` you need to use the branch name. Or you manually set the branch pointer to the new `E` commit afterwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore linear git history after nonlinear merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328341/how-to-restore-linear-git-history-after-nonlinear-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "by hand" approach would be:

```
git checkout --detach C
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick E
```

Then you can set a branch over here:

```
git branch -f some-branch
git checkout some-branch
```

Comment: Or replace the first command by `git checkout -b some-branch C`, then the last two commands are not necessary.