# Delete a merge commit middle of other commits

Tags: git, git-commit

In our team, we maintain `flat git history` by rebasing from other branches. And squash-merge from `feature` branch to `dev` branch.

Mistakenly, I merged a branch into another branch. After merging, I also committed a few changes in the current branch and pushed. Then I found that we don't do that. My current git history looks like this.

[image]

As you can see, I don't need that merged commit. I want to remove that commit preserving previous and later commits. If I can remove that commit completely, I can easily rebase that branch again.

How I can do that?

One way could be, didn't try yet though, I can create a new branch cherry-pick the changes, and delete this branch from local and remote.

Answer (score 0):

If these changes are local, not pushed, try using git rebase -i
Below are some tutorials (unfortunately they do not include the deletion option) on how to use git rebase -i

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e26Zx9K3cdQ&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=Du%C5%A1anDimitri%C4%87
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CsY1qXCs_0&t=23s&ab_channel=Du%C5%A1anDimitri%C4%87

Also check if this thread will not solve your problem

- [git remove merge commit from history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577409/git-remove-merge-commit-from-history)