# Remove past (double) merge commits from history

Tags: git, rebase

I'd like to perform the following transformation in Git : To remove the 2 merge commits and replace them with individual commits from the 2 green and pink branchs (I want a linear history)

[image]

I've checked the similar questions on SO, and I thought that these commands would simply do the job, without any conflict, since Git would be smart enough to use the merge commits when rebasing :

```sh
git checkout master
git rebase c
# (I am allowed to force-push btw)
git push --force
```

But I get an (unexpected for me) conflict during rebase because of commit C .... :(

Is there any way of achieving this linear commit history w/o any conflict to be resolved ? Should I do it in two+ steps ?

NOTE1: There are actually many more commits between E and D, between c and a and between 1 and 2, so I'd like to avoid tedious manual cherry-picks.... :) (I've posted a simplified graph for the question)

NOTE2: It works fine when there is only one merge commits, following the 3rd tip in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921732). But here there are 2 merge commits as you can see in the pic.

Thanks in advance for your help ?

Comment: You *can* do this sort of thing with `git rebase`, but the right way to do this is ... not to do it. Seriously, don't do it. It's not worth the effort. I've done it myself before, it wasn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the individual commits, choose to [fast-forward merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge) when you do

Because you've merged *already*, you should be able to re-merge the commits or [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) 'em over (though this is almost-certainly worse and much less-obvious than leaving things as they are)

---

In your example, if there are any conflicting changes in the other branches merged after `C`, you'll need to regenerate it into some `C'`, which contains the merge conflict fix of the branch and `C`

Additionally, the history *is* linear, and assuming the unlabeled merge of the pink branch before `D` is a squash merge on top of `C` in your example, that merge actually contains both

- all the commits in the pink branch
- any merge conflict changes needed (a form of this fix is needed and what git is complaining about when you attempted to rebase)

You can show this by attempting to revert it [How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

---

What you probably want in the future is to periodically merge your main branch into your development branch

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not my commit history, I am actually cleaning up a mess of staled branches and a merge conflicts galore...

I've edited my question to mention that there are actually many more commits between E and D, between c and a and between 1 and 2, so I'd like to avoid tedious manual cherry-picks.... :) (I've posted a simplified graph for the question)

I've changed the repo settings to allow only fast forward merges... but I'd like to have the whole history linear (for changelog generation, git bisect usage, etc...)

Comment: Can I rebase master onto the green merge commit ? I guess no ?