# After successfully recovering from a mangled git rebase, calling git rebase again does not work properly

Tags: git, git-rebase

After mangling a `git rebase -i`, I eventually got the code into the state I want.

```
$ git log
55c602ed1c (HEAD -> main) 
6c3fa102c2 (detached-branch) 
6ec87486d1 
89dd40a86a 
f6f4b6edb2 
77742d9d69 
32b67d2a01 
...
```

The commit `55c602ed1c` is exactly correct.

However, when I now call `git rebase -i 6c3fa102c2` I get unexpected editor content:

```
pick 77742d9d69
pick f6f4b6edb2
pick 89dd40a86a

# Rebase 6c3fa102c2..55c602ed1c onto 6c3fa102c2 (3 commands)
#
# Commands:
# ...
```

Of course I was expecting to see

```
pick 6c3fa102c2
pick 55c602ed1c

# Rebase 6c3fa102c2..55c602ed1c onto 6c3fa102c2 (3 commands)
#
# Commands:
# ...
```

Now I quit the editor without saving and get a message and errors:

```
Auto-merging ...
CONFLICT ... 
<more conflicts>
```

so I do `git rebase --abort` to get out of that, which leaves the branch in the correct state, but still unable to rebase.

How can I get back the normal rebasing function?

---

EDIT:
Removing `reflog` output, and removing the question, while adding new content and question.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   55c602ed1c (HEAD -> main)
r|g\  
r|   * 6c3fa102c2 (detached-branch) 
r|   * 6ec87486d1
 *  g| 89dd40a86a
 *  g| f6f4b6edb2
 *  g| 77742d9d69 
r|g/  
* 32b67d2a01
```

The actual graph output is color coded red and green , so I prefixed `|`,`/`, and `\` with a letter to indicate actual color.

For the record, the command used to create the final, good, commit `55c602ed1c` were:

```
git checkout main
git merge detached-branch
```

and it required manual conflict resolution.

I have tried rebasing to the common ancestor `32b67d2a01`, which is suggested in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17577876/4376643), but oddly neither the HEAD commit `55c602ed1c` nor the common ancestor `32b67d2a01` appear in the list shown in the editor:

```
git rebase -i 32b67d2a01
```

pops up editor with

```
pick 77742d9d69 
pick f6f4b6edb2 
pick 89dd40a86a 
pick 6ec87486d1 
pick 6c3fa102c2

# Rebase 32b67d2a01..55c602ed1c onto 6ec87486d1 (5 commands)
#
# Commands:
```

Using a tilde as in the hint given by @eftshift0 (without understanding the principle behind it and not seeing it on the git man mage for rebase)

```
git rebase -i 32b67d2a01~
```

gives

```
pick 32b67d2a01
pick 77742d9d69 
pick f6f4b6edb2 
pick 89dd40a86a 
pick 6ec87486d1 
pick 6c3fa102c2

# Rebase db737eb68b..55c602ed1c onto 89dd40a86a (6 commands)
#
# Commands:
```

but still, the HEAD commit `55c602ed1c` is not listed on the bottom.
If I go ahead and do the rebase with that selection, `55c602ed1c` is ignored and I am asked to resolve conflicts all over again, which obviously I don't want to do because `55c602ed1c` is already merged and satisfactory.

The new question is *how can I remove the commits between but not including HEAD and the common ancestor, while keeping HEAD (obviously)*?

Comment: `(detached-branch)` ... are you working from the detached HEAD state?

Comment: In the course of getting back to where I wanted I was in detached head and from that created a branch "detached-head", then merged than back into main and resolved some conflicts manually.  The criitcal point is - unlike other question I could find, I have the correct code already (finally) in branch "main".  Now I just can't get `git rebase -i` to work correctly.

Comment: Note that rebasing over merge commits does probably not work as you think.

Comment: That's interesting.  In what way does it work - and why can it not work as I expect?

Comment: When you rebase over merge commits, you need to manually tell Git which parent you want to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've moved forward in understanding the problem and updated it - but still am unable to clean up - it won't let me keep the the already merged and satisfactory HEAD commit, at least not using `rebase -i <last common ancestor>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to the final question:

```
git reset --soft 32b67d2a01
git commit -m "everything past 32b67d2a01 in a single shot"
```

That should work, no conflict to resolve. You are losing (**and rewriting**) history, of course, but I think that is the ultimate goal, right?

Answer (score 1):

I there there are a few things there. Let's solve the easy one.

You were expecting to see:

```
pick 6c3fa102c2
pick 55c602ed1c
```

That's not gonna happen. Well... only one part of it would happen, the second pick... but you will *not* get the first one because that is the commit you used as the base in the interactive call.... that commit is *not* rebased. If you had done `git rebase -i 6c3fa102c2~`, tnen you would see that commit show up in the list.

Then, the second one is a little trickier. I *think* `55c602ed1c` is a merge commit (can you check using `git log --oneline --graph`?). One of the parents being `6c3fa102c2`... so, `git rebase -i 6c3fa102c2` will list the commits that are part of the *other* side of the merge commit (and given that `55c602ed1c` is a merge commit and you did *not* use `--rebase-merges`, it doesn't show up in the list of commits to rebase).

Comment: `git rebase -i 6c3fa102c2` shows up in the editor with a line 'noop' and completes successfully.  But I see you have written `git rebase -i 6c3fa102c2~`, what does the tilde mean?  (Sorry I will offline for a while now).

Comment: That is not what you state in the question: _I get unexpected editor content_ then you list 3 picks, none of them is `6c3fa102c2`. Perhaps you are referring to another rebase attempt you tried? `~` means _the first parent of_. `6c3fa102c2~` is _the first parent of `6c3fa102c2`_.

Comment: Sorry I meant 55c602ed1c produced "noop".

Comment: Thanks for the advice which I have followed as best I can, but am still unable to clean up.  The question has been updated.